# Why are the id of method between instance object and class object not same?

Tags: python, function, methods

I am wondering why the `method` exist two copy, one for instance object, the other for class object, why it is designed like this?

```py
class Bar():
    def method(self):
        pass
    @classmethod
    def clsmethod(cls):
        pass
b1 = Bar()
b2 = Bar()
print(Bar.method,id(Bar.method))
print(b1.method,id(b1.method))
print(b2.method,id(b2.method))

print(Bar.clsmethod,id(Bar.clsmethod))
print(b1.clsmethod,id(b1.clsmethod))
print(b2.clsmethod,id(b2.clsmethod))
```

Comment: Would you expect `b1.method()`, `b2.method()` and `Bar.method()` to *behave the same*…?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This design is based on [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), specifically [non-data descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#descriptor-protocol). Every function happens to be a non-data descriptor by defining a `__get__` method:

```py
>>> def foo():
...     pass
... 
>>> foo.__get__
<method-wrapper '__get__' of function object at 0x7fa75be5be50>
```

When you have an expression `x.y` in your code, this means the attribute `y` is being looked up on the object `x`. The specific rules are [explained here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#overview-of-descriptor-invocation), and one of them is concerned with `y` being a (non-)data descriptor stored on the class of `x` (or any subclass). The following is an example:

```py
>>> class Foo:
...     def test(self):
...         pass
...
```

Here `Foo.test` looks up the name `test` on the class `Foo`. The result is the function as you would define in the global namespace:

```py
>>> Foo.test
<function Foo.test at 0x7fa75be5bf70>
```

However, as we have seen above, every function is also a descriptor, so if you look up `test` on an *instance* of `Foo`, it will call the descriptor's `__get__` method to compute the result:

```py
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.test
<bound method Foo.test of <__main__.Foo object at 0x7fa75bf56b20>>
```

We can obtain a similar result by manually invoking `Foo.test.__get__`:

```py
>>> Foo.test.__get__(f, type(f))
<bound method Foo.test of <__main__.Foo object at 0x7fa75bf56b20>>
```

This mechanism is what ensures that the instance (typically denoted via `self`) is passed as the first argument to instance methods. The descriptor returns a *bound method* (bound to the instance on which the lookup was performed) rather than the original function. This bound method inserts the instance as the very first parameter when being called. Every time you do `Foo.test` a new bound-method object is returned and hence their `id`s differ.

The situation with `classmethod`s is similar where [`Foo.test.__get__(None, Foo)`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#invocation-from-a-class) is called. The only difference is that for instances `object.__getattribute__` is called while for classes `type.__getattribute__` takes precedence.

```py
>>> class Bar:
...     @classmethod
...     def test(cls):
...         pass
... 
>>> Bar.test
<bound method Bar.test of <class '__main__.Bar'>>
>>> Bar.__dict__['test'].__get__(None, Bar)
<bound method Bar.test of <class '__main__.Bar'>>
```

Comment: but as I have tested, every time I do `Foo.test` it returns an object with the same id. so does the `f.test`

Comment: I know why `print(id(f.test))` always print the same value, because each time the `__get__` method of `A.test` returns a bound method object, but no one will receive or keep it, then it will be released, and in the next syntax, a bound method is allocated in the previous position, hence the id is same.

Comment: @Gordon Indeed the memory space is freed and then reused. You'll need to compare `f.test is f.test` which evaluates to `False`.